# A procedure with WAITFOR DELAY doesn't execute until the end

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure that I basically use for a timeout for a certain task. The user has to finish this task within 3 minutes otherwise they fail. Here's how it looks like:

```
--Perform an insert statement that notifies the user that they have 3 minutes to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 2 minutes 30 seconds remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 2 minutes remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 1 minute 30 seconds remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 1 minute remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 30 seconds remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have 10 seconds remaining to finish this task
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
IF EXISTS(SELECT*FROM _Users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND isDone=0)
--Perform another insert statement that notifies the user that they have failed to complete the task within the required time frame.
```

For some reason though, the procedure always stops when there's 1 minute left. I noticed that when I manually execute this procedure, it works just fine, but when I execute through another procedure which is also executed by another procedure, it stops when there's 1 minute left.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

PS: I do not own the source code of the application which executes this procedure, nor can I ask for any modifications to handle the time out within the source code, thus, I have to do it with a procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by *stops* - does it never return to the caller, do the final inserts never happen? If you add a final insert into a separate logging table, does that happen? It's also a pretty ugly bit of code, a simple loop decrementing a time remaining would be far more elegant.

Comment: If your procedure works correctly when directly executed, then the problem can only be at a higher level. TBH this is a bizarre way of implementing a countdown timer. Impossible to make suggestions without a deeper knowledge of this application and how these layers of procedures are designed and intended to be used. Three minutes (plus whatever delays are caused by your actual SQL statements) is a LONG time to wait - I suspect that may be a big problem.

Comment: It seems that using service broker to asynchronously execute this procedure fixed the issue. I'd love to know what is the best way you can think of to handle this timeout though. Edit: by "the procedure stops when there's 1 minute left, I meant that the final insert statements are not executed